# getting IP address

Tags: c#

how to get the IP Address of all the systems connected to a network regardless of operating system(windows,Linux,Unix) using C#.net

Comment: I don't think the OP is suggesting it needs to, this is more a network discovery tool running on a single system, which can therefore presumably be Windows...?

Comment: @S.Mark: Of course it does. Mono works perfectly on Linux/Unix.

Answer (score 1):

Simple question, but you stumbled on a hard problem.

There is **no definitive answer** because network stacks vary. Internal firewalls may eat your packets. Hosts may not send ping replies. Routers may throw away their ARP cache (or may have been reset recently). Et cetera.

Please read the [Nmap network scanning](http://nmap.org/book/) book.

Answer (score 0):

Loop on all possible ip's within desired range and ping them... Should be possible in every computing language.

Answer (score 0):

Periodically query your Router via SNMP for its ARP-Cache => You also get these systems whose admins think a ping is a security breach.

If you have more than one Router: Ask your Router for its routing-table and follow next-hops...